# Where is the inclinometer "ball" in a knife edged turn?

Tags: general-aviation, aerobatics

Discussion of steep turns has lead to a question about where the inclinometer ball would be 
if the plane rolled to 90 degrees.  Also, would there be any difference if the plane simply rolled to 90 degrees, rolled to 90 degrees and maintained altitude in a straight path with rudder, or rolled to 90 degrees and executed a "knife edged turn?

Does the ball become irrelevant at these attitudes?

Answer (score 4):

As it was pointed out in the other thread, the ball just rolls around inside a curved glass tube.  It doesn't know what the angle of bank is, or anything other than what direction gravity, and/or centrifugal force is moving it.  Therefore:

At 90 deg AOB in coordinated flight at positive G, the ball would be centered.  The aircraft in this case would be in a descending spiral.

At 90 deg AOB in a "knife edge" straight pass where altitude is maintained with rudder, gravity will pull the ball towards the earth.  Same thing if you were able to make a knife edge turn holding altitude with rudder.

Comment: It isn't possible to be in coordinated flight at 90 degrees angle of bank, is it?

Comment: Why not?  You can be in coordinated flight inverted.  I didn't say you could do it while maintaining altitude.

Comment: Have you seen the video of Bob Hoover pouring iced tea while doing a barrel roll?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking too narrowly.

Comment: It would be good to point out that in knife edge flight where rudder is being used to hold the nose up and there is no elevator input, the FUSELAGE is the wing and the wing is unloaded and doing nothing, just big fins sticking up and down.  In that case it's not really a turn.

Comment: I think if you are at 90 deg and still pulling, there is zero vertical lift vector so you are kind of in a ballistic spiral.

Comment: "At 90 deg AOB in coordinated flight at positive G, the ball would be centered. The aircraft in this case would be in a descending spiral." Mmmm, lemme run the numbers on that. If the bank angle not either 0 or 180 (meaning the lateral axis is not parallel to the horizon), then the only way the ball can be centered is if the aircraft is experiencing a lateral acceleration. For bank angles less than about, say, 75, this can be accomplished by making a coordinated turn. But steady coordinated flight at a bank angle of 90 degrees is impossible.

Comment: At 90 degrees of bank, and 0 degrees pitch (meaning the nose is pointed at the horizon), the situation is the most extreme: the only way to be in coordinated flight here is to be accelerating at 1 g downwards, which is to say, to be in freefall. So it's not correct to say that the aircraft would be in a descending spiral; it would have to be in a ballistic arc instead.

Comment: @Tanner Swett, I never said it would be steady state.  You are correct, it wouldn’t last very long…  One thing they teach you in IFR training is to recognize the dreaded “death spiral”.  With no horizon, (artificial or actual) if the aircraft starts a descending turn the pilot’s instinct is to pull back on the stick to correct.  As bank increases more backstick is applied and the spiral tightens as altitude lost increases.  The aircraft may transition though 90 deg AOB in coordinated flight.  If the condition isn’t recognized and corrected the aircraft will corkscrew right into the ground.

Comment: I also never said the pitch would be zero...